# Improving mysql database performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have mysql database of containing 2GB data in data in database.when i join 3 tables and execute a query then it will take so much to execute.

can any one please tell me how to improve mysql performance so that i can get faster result from database.

thank you so much 
Gajanan Hiroji.

Comment: Dear Hamza Kubba, I know that and i did but i didnt get anything much so i posted question here right. please do whatever you said me to do and let me know if you get anything.. thank you hamza...

Comment: Here's the very first result I got. Have you tried these?
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/
It doesn't seem like you put in any effort into it, so why should others put in any effort to help you out?

Answer (score 0):

EXPLAIN `<your query>`

and then
refer [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) one.

Comment: basically i am accessing data in tableau which is one reporting tool. i am not writing my own query tableau will write own query and execute it. is there any technique  which i can use to optimization.